# why is the feedback or gate resistance RG necessary?

Tags: feedback, nmos, biasing, stable

Here the large feedback resistance RG interposed between gate and drain of the NMOS (usually in the megohm range) forces the dc voltage at the gate to be equal to that at the drain (because IG = 0). Also, it says that RG works just like the RS which is to stabilize the bias current ID in the event of changing VGS.
my question is why is the RG necessary, isn't "the dc voltage at the gate = the dc voltage at the drain" regardless of the RG?

[image]

thank you folks

Comment: Do you mean "why not make Rg zero in value?"

Comment: *it says that RG works just like the RS* What Rs? I see no Rs present.

Comment: See also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519342/what-is-the-r-c-feedback-to-this-fet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gate of a MOSFET is floating. There will be a bit of leakage (typically nA or less level at room temperature), and there is capacitance between the gate and drain and gate and source. So applying a voltage to the circuit without Rg will result in the gate taking on some intermediate voltage and slowly drifting up or down as the leakage current charges the capacitance (and the Miller capacitance affects the gate voltage once the drain voltage starts to move).

To bias the MOSFET into the active region so it will work as an amplifier, in this case, you want the gate to follow the drain (at low frequencies approaching DC) and the gate to follow the input voltage for higher frequencies, which is accomplished by using a coupling capacitor.

So a high value of Rg does not affect the input voltage too much but allows the bias to settle out in a reasonable length of time. For this we want the maximum leakage current multiplied by Rg to be a low voltage, and we want the coupling capacitor plus MOSFET capacitance including Miller capacitance multiplied by Rg to be a reasonable length of time for start-up. For example, if Rg is 1uF and the coupling capacitor is 1uF it would take a few seconds for the amplifier to settle down.

Answer (score 3):

I think, the shown circuit will be used as an amplifier. For this purpose, an input signal will be applied - and in this context one key word must be mentioned: **NEGATIVE FEEDBACK**. Two cases are to be considered:

1.)  DC negative feedback is necessary to stabilize the DC bias point against tolerances and temperature changes. For this purpose, an input coupling capacitor is necessary - otherwise the DC feedback signal would be shorted by the signal source.

2.) For signals to be amplified (AC) we also want negative feedback in most cases. For this purpose, an additional Resistor R1 in series with the coupling capacitor is necessary. Now, the feedback factor for AC will be k=R1/(R1+RG). This feedback arrangement is similar to the well-known inverting opamp stage.

3.) Interpretation: With the above modifications, the gain stage has negative feedback for DC as well as for AC signals. Insofar, the circuit can be compared with another alternative which provides also DC and AC feedback: A resistor RS in the path between source and ground.

4.) Comment: The values of the two resistors (R1, RG) - in particular RG - determine the signal input resistance, which is a very important parameter for each amplifier. For his reason, RG must have a value that is sufficiently large (because it will be reduced due to the MILLER effect).

Answer (score 1):

The gate of a MOSFET behaves as a capacitor, for DC analysis we consider it an open so nothing is connected. As nothing is else connected at the gate node, no current can flow so there will be no voltage drop across Rg.

So when **only** considering the DC solution (static voltages and currents), Rg **does nothing**. So whether Rg = zero ohm (a short) or any other real value (not infinite ohms) **makes no difference.

This changes if we would consider gate leakage.

This changes if we consider time variant signals to be present.

Suppose I inject a small signal current into the drain of the NMOS.

When I inject a high frequency signal it will be filtered out by the RC filter consisting of Rg and the gate capacitance. So there will be little AC signal on the gate of the NMOS.

If the signal is of a very low frequency (a frequency below the cutoff point of the filter consisting of Rg and the gate capacitance) there is no filtering and the gate of the NMOS will follow the drain voltage.

To properly evaluate this behavior you will need to draw a small signal equivalent circuit and analyze it.

The resistor actually **isn't necessary**, it is **optional**. I mostly do not add a gate resistor in my designs unless I have a valid reason to do so. One valid reason is to influence the frequency response of this type of circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Mosfet gates are effectively isolated from drain and source.

This means that the trace connected to a gate (but not connected otherwise) can act as an antenna creating spurious triggers or the gate can end up with a voltage in the linear region of the mosfet.