# What is the R-C Feedback to this FET?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, rf, feedback, powermosfet

I'm studying this [RF Power Amplifier](http://www.iosrjournals.org/iosr-jece/papers/Conf-%20ICFTE%E2%80%9916/Volume-1/1.%2001-04.pdf) and I'm curious about the drain-gate feedback shown as R3 and C6:

- What is the purpose of the R-C feedback?
- What is this mechanism known as?

[image: RF Amplifier Circuit with R-C feedback]

Comment: The shown R-C feedback has the same purpose as ALL signal feedback schemes:  Setting/control of the gain value and better linearity (lower distortion).

Comment: It all depends on what the circuit is intended to do. That, unfortunately is unclear in your half-complete schematic.

Comment: @Andyaka, the linked paper on page 3 has the entire schematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That, for high open loop gain (e, g. very inductive), sets the voltage gain and lowers distortion.

Imagine a 50 ohm Rsource and that 500 ohm Rfeedback.

Maximum voltage gain is -10x.

=======================================

By the way, a resistive feedback will alter the S12 (S_param feedback gain/phase) and perhaps greatly alter the stability factors/circles.

Comment: I think I understand the -10x (500/50==10), but why -10x and not +10x?

Comment: Lets reference this post too, it helped me understand the situation: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383287/why-is-the-feedback-or-gate-resistance-rg-necessary .  Still curious why it is negative feedback and not positive feedback.